# kusto project from different instances

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to query multiple instances of Application Insights, but project certain fields from each? For example, I want to query traces from one instance and requests from another. I have:

```
union 
(requests
| where url contains "5a1abbe0-97b5-4da0-bb6f-94d5841ad92e"
| project url, name),
app("app2").traces
| where message contains "5a1abbe0-97b5-4da0-bb6f-94d5841ad92e"
| project message
```

This only shows me the message and not the url and name of the request. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the 2nd query block `app("app2").traces | where xx | project xxx` inside `()`,

Like this:

```
union 
(requests
| where url contains "5a1abbe0-97b5-4da0-bb6f-94d5841ad92e"
| project url, name),
(app("app2").traces
| where message contains "5a1abbe0-97b5-4da0-bb6f-94d5841ad92e"
| project message)
```

It works well at my side:

[image]